# No response status in ajax call not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following ajax call which is made to my spring mvc app..

```
        alert("ready");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: document.location.toString()+ "/dashboard",
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                alert(response.status);                                             
                $("#frameBody").contents().find("html").html(response);
                // we have the response
                if(response.status == "SUCCESS") {

                    alert(response);
                    // do nothing..
                    // check for no content... if there is content... replace iframe
                    // $("#frameBody").attr('src', jsonObj.url);
                    // $(""#frameBody").contents().find("html").html(response);
                }
                else {  
                    // do nothing yet
                }
             },
             error: function(e){
                $("#errors").attr("style", "display:inline")
                $('#errors').html(e.responseText);
                window.setTimeout("fadeErrorsDiv();", 5000);
             }
        });
```

my mvc controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public String dashboard(Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {

    int i = 0;

    return "login";
}
```

My question is that i cant see why this is not producing the response status that i expect?... it gives me undefined when i check for response.status in javascript?.. any idea why

Answer (score 0):

See [JQuery .get docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). It would seem your "response" object inside your success callback will actually be "login". Therefore you're infact trying to do "login".status.